# Is it secure to overwrite unencrypted files with encrypted ones?

Tags: encryption, deletion

If I have a text file on my desktop and I encrypt it (as in replace it with an encrypted version, not create a secondary file) will the old file still be recoverable? In other words if you replace the content of a text file is the old text still recoverable?

Deleted files are fairly easy to recover so that made me wonder if previous versions of a file is the same.

Comment: What filesystem are you using?

Comment: am using NTFS but some of my systems are FAT32

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I infer two things from this question, so I will explain the first. You have a text file (we'll name it `test.txt`) My first interpretation:

1. Open text file
2. Select all content
3. Overwrite content with encrypted content
4. Save file

If you never copied unencrypted data, the data would be cached so it would be retrievable. If you're using Windows, depending on the version, you could do it with [Volume Shadow Copy](https://help.med.unc.edu/guide/operating-systems/recovering-overwritten-files-in-windows-xp-and-vista)

Second interpretation. You have a file called `test.txt` and a file called `encrypted-test.txt` and you are copying/moving `encrypted-test.txt` to `test.txt`. In this instance the data is gone. In order to understand why, you will need to learn forensics, or [read a briefer on it](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/impossible-recover-data-overwritten-hard-drive-technology-explained/).

The tl;dr version: Deleted data isn't really deleted. Bits are re-assigned, and marked as available. While data is still visible on your disk, it is invisible to the naked eye. Until your disk reaches full circle to overwrite those segments, it can be retrieved. If data is **OVERWRITTEN** it is usually gone, but *can be* (possible) recovered. You *may be* able to retrieve fragments of the content of the overwritten file, but the entire data... It's gone.

> When a sector is overwritten it is exactly that.  The previous data is
>   all overwritten and lost.  With earlier disk drives, maybe pre year
>   2000, it was occasionally possible, with government budgets to recover
>   data from some overwritten sectors and this has caused a lot of ‘folk
>   law’ about such recovery.  With a modern, very high density drive
>   drive this is now impossible, and any software package that say it is
>   possible is ‘being creative’.  The only way to recover an overwritten
>   file is by finding another copy - often called a backup. ([source](https://www.cnwrecovery.com/html/overwritten.html))

To answer your question: "Is it secure to overwrite files..." It is an uncommon way, but will work. If the goal is to make a file irretrievable, here is a horrible method to do so. Make an mp3, rename the mp3 to `test.txt` then overwrite it two or three times. Many forensics tools will attempt to fix the headers and trailers for file carving (identification). So mp3 headers become txt file headers. The entire document is now gibberish.

Comment: One VERY important note: you have no guarantees that "overwriting" the file will cause the bits to be in the same spot on the disk. The filesystem may decide to put it elsewhere for whatever reason (after copying it around to avoid fragmentation, making *more* copies!), and if you're using an SSD it may write it to a different block (so the old one is still there, just in a different physical spot!).

Comment: About formatting: why of all the words in your answer did you choose to emphasize "*overwritten*"? I read the question, move my eyes to the answer and first thing I see is: **OVERWRITTEN**. The next thing I do is: read the sentence containing it and expect that to be the essence. I don't get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to overwriting data, there's so much that the filesystem and hardware do for optimizations that cause issues. If it's a HDD, an overwrite of free-space will do it (if you've gotten rid of all caches, backups, etc, and deleted the unencrypted file). If it's a SSD/flash-drive, **there is no sanitization procedure** besides "Kinetic Sanitization" (i.e. smash it with a hammer).